# Problem with auto log in

Tags: 13.10, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I have installed several desktop-environments. When one is used, next time, I'm automatically logged in it (without entering log-in password).

The problem is that I logged into a desktop environment (cinnamon), but it seems to be incompatible with my computer and the computer hangs immediately (after log-in). Even if I restart the computer; again, I'll be logged into the same desktop automatically and the computer freezes again. No way to escape except command line.

Is there a command to change the default log-in on next restart. Or a way to prevent auto-log-in in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get to a command line you can remove the Cinnamon desktop and should get out of the loop since Cinnamon will not be a valid desktop after rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands on terminal to uninstall cinnamon desktop,

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now you can't ran into problem.

And also you can't switch between different desktop environments via terminal.You can select the desktop environment only in the login screen.

See [**this**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Change_the_Default_Session) link to change default sessions.